# Next.js: image imports stopped working after updating NextJS from 14.0.1 to 14.1.1

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I have a small project built on NextJS and using App Router. A have several places where I use `Image` component and based on [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images#local-images) I'm importing image itself.

After updating `next` from 14.0.1 to 14.1.1, I've got build errors related to `.png` and `.svg` imports:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/dashboards/MyComponent.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'public/images/image.png'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/admin/page.tsx
```

I'm getting similar error for every `.png` and `.svg` being imported.

I'm trying to find all the responsible pieces for image importing and would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: Do you import the images with string in the `src` prop, like 
`<Image src="public/images/image.png" />` ?
Seems that your url is incorrect, if you have the files in your public folder, should be `/images/image.png`     .     



Edit: seems like you import directly your image with a `import MyImage from "public/images/image.png"` , maybe you should try to import it with a relative path, like  `import MyImage from "../../../public/images/image.png"`

Comment: Using relative path worked, thanks! But is there any reason why it was working on 14.0 and stopped working on the 14.1?
P.S. Feel free to publish it as an answer, so I can accept it